# Change scaling of plot using plotPredictSurvProb in R

Tags: r, plot, survival

Here's some example code that produces the kind of plot I have:

```
library(survival)
library(rms)
library(pec)
library(prodlim)

ndat <- data.frame(X1=c(0.25,0.25,-0.05,0.05),X2=c(0,1,0,1))
d <- SimSurv(100)
ttt <- sort(unique(d$time))

coxmodel <- cph(Surv(time,status)~X1+X2,data=d,surv=TRUE)

plotPredictSurvProb(coxmodel,newdata=ndat,times=ttt, percent = TRUE)
```

This generates a plot where survival probability ticks are shown every 25% on the Y-axis. My actual data has survival above 50%, and when I create the plot, I get just one tick at 75% and another showing 100% on top. This is a lot less resolution than I need and just doesn't look good; I'd rather be showing ticks every 10%. Likewise, I would also like to have control of the tick marks on the X-axis also, which (for my data) is showing a tick every 100 units and I'd rather have a tick every 50 at least.

I do indeed want my Y-axis to show whole-number percentages like it shows now. The actual survival data is on a scale of 0 to 1, and I haven't figured out how I can extract that data and modify it to a 0-100 scale, so I am not sure what I can do to get control of the Y-axis here. Any help?

I'm also not working in ggplot as you can see, and I don't really need to be, though if it makes figuring this out easier then I'm fine with that.

Finally, I'm plugging this plot into a shiny app, so it needs to be versatile. I can't use a one-time solution to edit plots manually since I will be generating new plots at will.